# How to print once until the if condition is broken?

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

this is my code the I am currently writing for a robot in my university project. This code works, however the loop will constantly print statements every second and I would like it to only print when I change the input condition (break the if condition), so it wouldn't keep on printing. Is there anyway to fix this? Thanks for the help in advance.

PS: this is in python 2.7 (I think)

```
try:
    while True:
        #some stuff 
        if 0.01 < joystick.get_axis(1) <= 0.25:
            print ('moving backward with 25% speed')
            # performing some actions


        elif 0.25 < joystick.get_axis(1) <= 0.5:
            print ('moving forward with 50% speed')
            # performing some actions

        elif 0.5 < joystick.get_axis(1) <= 0.75:
            print ('moving backward with 75% speed')
            # performing some actions
```

the while loop continues in the same fashion...

Comment: *if loop*? You only have a `while` loop.

Comment: Its doing exactly what you're asking it to - check every iteration in which range the values falls into. THen go into that IF, then print(). Add an outer IF statement that englobes everything (in the while()) and compares to the previously obtained value would work. But then the whole structure isn't great and should be rethought...

Comment: Which print is the problem? Consider cutting out the stuff that doens't matter for the question. I'm looking at `GPIO.whatever` and wondering why!

Comment: I don't see where you are waiting for 1 second. Is it the `print ('moving backward with 25% speed')`  for instance? Do you want it to print again when the speed changes?

Comment: I stated every second because I couldn't really count how many times it will print, so it is just a figurative statement. But yes, I want it to only print again when the speed change

Comment: Edited your question - try to only put code that actually matters for your question, not the whole thing....

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the last category - something like that.

```
previous_category = 0
 while True:
        #some stuff 
    if 0.01 < joystick.get_axis(1) <= 0.25:
        if previous_category != 1:
           print ('moving backward with 25% speed')
        previous_category = 1
        # performing some actions

    elif 0.25 < joystick.get_axis(1) <= 0.5:
        if previous_category != 2:
           print ('moving forward with 50% speed')
        previous_category = 2
        # performing some actions

    elif 0.5 < joystick.get_axis(1) <= 0.75:
        if previous_category != 3:
           print ('moving backward with 75% speed')
        previous_category = 3
        # performing some actions
```

If you're down for reformating your code a bit, I think this would be a better approach:

```
 previous_category = 0
 while True:
    val = joystick.get_axis(1)

    if 0.01 < val <= 0.25:
    category = 1
    #add 2 elif for the other categories, 2 and 3 

    if category == 1:
        # performing some actions
    elif category == 2:
        # performing some actions

    elif category == 3:
        # performing some actions

    #now that we've moved the object, we check if we need to print or not
    if category != previous_category:
       print_statement(category)
    #and we update previous_category for the next round, which will just be the current category
    previous_category = category

def print_statement(category):
   #handle printing here based on type, this is more flexible
```

Comment: This is better than my answer because it accounts for any speed in a given range.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a global integer that stores the last value printed. Something like this:

```
_last_count = None
def condprint(count):
    global _last_count
    if count != _last_count:
        print('Waiting for joystick '+str(count))
        _last_count = count
```

Comment: You do not need a global, this can easily be handled via proper use of variable scopes.